# Is there a way to extract "event_type" from an event on Forex Factory from the "inspect source" page using R Studio?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to extract what "event_type" an event is from Forex Factory's calendar page. For example if inspect the source code of the page "https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar?week=sep17.2023" I can find that on line 95 event types are stated as:

```
"event_types":{"1":"Growth","2":"Inflation","3":"Employment","4":"Central Bank","5":"Bonds","7":"Housing","8":"Consumer Surveys","9":"Business Surveys","10":"Speeches","11":"Misc"}
```

Now, I would expect that each event would have some sort of event_type_id associated with it. However, I can't seem to find where this value might be in the source code. On line 88 the events are listed. One of the events listed is as follows:

```
{"id":131238,"ebaseId":852,"name":"BusinessNZ Services Index","dateline":1694989800,"country":"NZ","currency":"NZD","hasLinkedThreads":true,"hasNotice":false,"hasGraph":true,"checkedIn":false,"isMasterList":false,"firstInDay":true,"showGridLine":true,"greyed":true,"upNext":false,"releaser":"JS","checker":"TR","impactClass":"icon--ff-impact-yel","impactTitle":"Low Impact Expected","timeLabel":"6:30pm","actual":"47.1","previous":"47.8","revision":"48.0","forecast":"","leaked":false,"actualBetterWorse":0,"revisionBetterWorse":0,"isSubscribable":true,"isSubscribed":false,"showDetails":false,"showGraph":false,"enableDetailComponent":false,"enableExpandComponent":false,"enableActualComponent":false,"showExpanded":false,"siteId":1,"editUrl":"","date":"Sep 17, 2023","url":"\/calendar?day=sep17.2023#detail=131238"}
```

Nowhere in here do I see something that may be referencing the "event_type". So how does the website know which events to filter for when a user filters the calendar? There must be a way to extract that information that I'm missing. For example, if that event corresponds to an event ID of "1" which is "Growth", where is that information?

I would like to web-scrape this information!

Comment: you could construct the mapping by mimicking the POST requests made when you select each event_type. The event_type goes in the payload and the events are returned in the JSON response. There is no client-side easy mapping to grab AFAIKS.

Comment: @QHarr I'm a little new to this, is there a good way to do that? The URL doesn't change at all when filters are applied. I guess my question is how would I mimic the POST request?

Comment: https://scrapecrow.com/reverse-engineering-intro.html https://www.etiennebacher.com/posts/2023-05-09-making-post-requests-with-r/

Comment: you can also right-click the relevant POST in network tab and copy as curl bash and convert https://curlconverter.com/r/ that tool will provide more info than likely needed but is a start. With practice one can usually reduce the provided code down to minimum actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you would look for. Like QHarr has suggested you can filter for each event type individually and this way reversely determine which event type belongs to each event.

```r
library(httr2)

## recreate basic post request with just one event type
data = '{"default_view":"this_week","impacts":[3,2,1,0],"event_types":[1],"currencies":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],"begin_date":"September 17, 2023","end_date":"September 23, 2023"}'

## make character vector with all event types in sequence
post_data <- stringr::str_c('{"default_view":"this_week","impacts":[3,2,1,0],"event_types":[',
             1:11,
             '],"currencies":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],"begin_date":"September 17, 2023","end_date":"September 23, 2023"}')

result <- purrr::map2_dfr( ## loop over different event types
  post_data, ## provide vector with different event type requests
  1:11,
  ~ request( 
    "https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar/apply-settings/1?navigation=0"
  ) |> ## create request with url in httr2
    req_headers("User-Agent" = "macosx, Rstudio, httr2") |> ## provide a relatively random user agent, because the default httr2 seems to be alerady blocked
    req_verbose() |> ## make the requests verbose so we can check what is send
    req_throttle(rate = 10 / 60) |> ## set a throttle, so we cont get instantly blocked
    req_body_raw(.x) |> ## tell map where to provide the post data information
    req_perform() |> ## perform the request
    resp_body_json(simplifyVector = T) |> ## extract the json
    purrr::pluck("days") |> ## get the days event information
    tidyr::unnest(events, names_repair = "unique") |> ## make a nicer data frame without nested datastructure
    dplyr::mutate(event_id = .y) ## remember which event type we just provided by putting the post data
)
```